# Accessing APACHE Remotely

Tags: server, remote-access, xampp

I have two machines A and B. I have connected both machines using UTP cabel. I have assigned an IP address to **Machine A (192.168.0.1)** and **Machine B (192.168.0.2)**. Machine A contains Ubuntu Server 11.10 with xampp server. I have created a php project that runs on machine A on xampp. Now I need to access this project on machine B. I have seen alot of posts but they are talking about routers and etc etc. Nothing giving me any clear idea. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite simple. Just go to **Machine A** and fireup browser. Type **//192.168.0.2/xampp**